# Code Review does not compare with newest version

Tags: tfs, tfvc, tfs-code-review

When using Visual Studio + TFS for Code Reviews, for some reason it does not compare to the right state of code. It compares to some old release (or branche?). Even tho, when using the TFS browser alternativ to check the Code changes, it shows the right changes (so this error only occurs when using visual studio).

Here is one example to understand the problem

- Pre Changed Code = A
- After Changing the Code = B
- Some old state of the class = C

When comparing I expect to see

- A and B

so i can see the exact difference between pre change and after change

For some reason I see

- A and C

Which means I dont see the new changes at all, instead se a nonsense compare with some old state and have to use the browser instead.

How can I fix this without losing the history of changes.

Comment: Unfortunately you're unlikely to get much help with this because the TFVC code review feature is very old, was never implemented particularly well, and will not receive future enhancements. TFVC is considered a legacy technology and is no longer receiving investments by Microsoft.